# many-to-many relationship with user

Tags: many-to-many, jhipster

Is it possible to make a Many-To-Many relationship to the user? I tried to make a simple entity

```json
{
    "relationships": [
        {
            "relationshipName": "leader",
            "otherEntityName": "user",
            "relationshipType": "many-to-many",
            "otherEntityField": "login",
            "ownerSide": true
        },
        {
            "relationshipName": "member",
            "otherEntityName": "user",
            "relationshipType": "many-to-many",
            "otherEntityField": "login",
            "ownerSide": true
        }
    ],
    "fields": [
        {
            "fieldName": "name",
            "fieldType": "String"
        }
    ],
    "changelogDate": "20160712043251",
    "dto": "mapstruct",
    "service": "no",
    "entityTableName": "team",
    "pagination": "no"
}
```

but when I select the users from the list and select Save it gives the error

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException:
> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:
> com.mycompany.myapp.domain.User; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.mycompany.myapp.domain.User

is it possible to make this relationship with user in jhipster?

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported by Jhipster for now, check this issue : https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/3827